# Robot Framework Browser Library: Save and access PDF file returned by server

Tags: robotframework, playwright

In my robot framework script I use the browser library to open a webpage and click on a button to get a receipt in PDF.
The button does not contain the direct link to the PDF: when you click the button, it opens a new page and after ~0.5 second the page returns a PDF file generated by the server.

I was not able to get and access the generated file in the Robot Framework script.

**My tentative #1**

I thought the PDF file could be captured by downloading it with a promise but it failed:

```
Click  button.okButton
Switch Page    NEW
${dl_promise}          Promise To Wait For Download    ./${SUITE_NAME}/downloads
${file_obj}=           Wait For  ${dl_promise}
File Should Exist    ${file_obj}[saveAs]
```

Failure:

[image: Tentative 1 not working]

**Tentative #1bis**

```
${dl_promise}          Promise To Wait For Download    ./${SUITE_NAME}/downloads
Click  button.okButton
Switch Page    NEW    
${file_obj}=           Wait For  ${dl_promise}
File Should Exist    ${file_obj}[saveAs]
```

Same failure (TimeoutError: page.waitForEvent: Timeout 20000ms exceeded while waiting for event "download")

**My tentative #2**

The new page source code is the following:

```
<html><head></head><body><embed name="9AF27FA0E167C8860EB51FD926BE211B" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="9AF27FA0E167C8860EB51FD926BE211B"></body></html>
```

I thought it is a local storage ID, am I right? So I tried the following:

```
Click  button.okButton
Switch Page    NEW
${sourceCode} =  Get Page Source
${storageItem} =  Get Regexp Matches  ${sourceCode}  (?<=(internalid="))(.*)(?=(">))
${myPDFfile} =  Local Storage Get Item  ${storageItem}
Log  ${myPDFfile}
```

But seems it does not work:

[image: Tentative 2 not working]

**... any idea how I should proceed? Thanks so much for your help and suggestions.**

Answer (score 0):

Keyword `Promise To Wait For Download` should be before triggering action. So the logic should be the following:

1. Promise
2. Trigger download
3. Wait for promise

Comment: Thanks @JaPyR ; I tried it but sadly it is failing too, with the same timeout on the download promise. I added Tentative #1bis in my initial post to illustrate. Thanks